# How to wrap links with <a> tags?

Tags: php, html, string, magento

In Magento I made attribute fields. And insert 4 links:

```
http://www.first-link.com/
http://www.second-link.com/
http://www.third-link.com/
http://www.fourth-link.com/
```

With

```
<?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getLinks(), 'links') ?>
```

I display this 4 naked links.

But I would like to wrap them with `<a>` tag to make something like this:

```
<a href="http://www.first-link.com/" target="_blank">Link 1 - description</a><br>
<a href="http://www.second-link.com/" target="_blank">Link 2 - description</a><br>
<a href="http://www.third-link.com/" target="_blank">Link 3 - description</a><br>
<a href="http://www.fourth-link.com/" target="_blank">Link 4 - description</a>
```

I got PHP 5.3 on server.

Answer (score 0):

i just hacked something together can be probably be solved much nicer

```
<?php 

$links = $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getLinks(), 'links');
$array = explode('http://',$links);

foreach ($array as $link) {
 if (empty($link)) continue;
 echo "<a href='http://".$link."' target='_blank'>Link 1 - description</a><br>";
}

?>
```

Comment: btw just tried it, it works. gotta find something for the link description though

Answer (score 0):

For description (or any other attribute)

```
$attributes = $_product->getAttributes();
$description = $attributes['description']->getFrontend()->getValue($_product);
echo $description;
```